# why the gpu memory is increasing when I set the parameters of the network? PyTorch

Tags: memory-leaks, pytorch

I'm conducting an experiment, but the gpu memory keeps increasing. By inspecting the codes line by line, I find that it is the following function that caused the memory leak. Can anyone help me find out the reason and the solution? It would be appreciated! Note that it is the **"set_param"** function.

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
   def update_params(self, lr_inner, first_order=False, source_params=None, detach=False):
        if source_params is not None:
            for tgt, src in zip(self.named_params(self), source_params):
                name_t, param_t = tgt
                # name_s, param_s = src
                # grad = param_s.grad
                # name_s, param_s = src
                grad = src
                if first_order:
                    grad = to_var(grad.detach().data)
                tmp = param_t - lr_inner * grad
                self.set_param(self, name_t, tmp)
        else:

            for name, param in self.named_params(self):
                if not detach:
                    grad = param.grad
                    if first_order:
                        grad = to_var(grad.detach().data)
                    tmp = param - lr_inner * grad
                    self.set_param(self, name, tmp)
                else:
                    param = param.detach_()
                    self.set_param(self, name, param)

    def set_param(self, curr_mod, name, param):
        if '.' in name:
            n = name.split('.')
            module_name = n[0]
            rest = '.'.join(n[1:])
            for name, mod in curr_mod.named_children():
                if module_name == name:
                    self.set_param(mod, rest, param)
                    break
        else:
            setattr(curr_mod, name, param)
```

Comment: It seems that the setattr function caused the memory leak, bacause when i comment the last line, there is no leak problem.  HOWEVER, I need to set the parameters. I cant just get rid of the setattr funtion. T_T

Comment: Why are you manually managing gradient and parameters update?

Comment: It's a long story, in the calculation of gradient, a matrix (say matrix A) is used, and I want the gradient to remember the calculation of A, so I can calculate the gadient of A in the next parameter upstate step. However, if I simply use optimizer to update the parameters, the gradient of A would be none.